# Pass array as argument to vmware_vm_shell module in Ansible (vm_shell_args)

Tags: powershell, ansible

I want to pass `vm_shell_args` (`vmware_vm_shell` Ansible module) to my PowerShell script which contains string and array. I am getting errors while passing array like below.

What is the proper way to pass an array to my PowerShell script from ansible?

-NIC @(("{{ vm_info['instance']['hw_eth0']['macaddress'] }}", "{{ network_primary_ip }}", "{{ network_primary_subnet }}", "{{ network_primary_gateway }}"),("{{ vm_info['instance']['hw_eth1']['macaddress'] }}", "{{ network_backup_ip }}", "{{ network_backup_subnet }}", ""))

```
- name: Run Pre Domain join Post Install Scripts Inside VM 
          vmware_vm_shell:
            hostname: "{{ vsphere_hostname }}"
            username: "{{ vsphere_username }}"
            password: "{{ vsphere_password }}"
            validate_certs: false
            vm_id: "{{ vm_name }}"
            vm_username: "{{ vm_username }}"
            vm_password: "{{ vm_password }}"
            vm_shell: "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
            vm_shell_args: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File Provisioning\\00_Customize-WindowsServer.ps1 -HyperVisor "local" -Location "{{ datacenter }}" -Environment "{{ environ }}" -Type "{{ type }}" -NIC @(("{{ vm_info['instance']['hw_eth0']['macaddress'] }}", "{{ network_primary_ip }}", "{{ network_primary_subnet }}", "{{ network_primary_gateway }}"),("{{ vm_info['instance']['hw_eth1']['macaddress'] }}", "{{ network_backup_ip }}", "{{ network_backup_subnet }}", "")) -Domain "{{ domain }}" -JoinUser "{{ domain }}\{{ vsphere_username }}" -JoinPassw "{{ vsphere_password }}" -Backup "N"
            vm_shell_cwd: "C:\\Temp\\"
            wait_for_process: true
          delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: In short: In order to pass _arrays_ to PowerShell scripts via the PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe` / `pwsh.exe`), you must use the  `-Command` (`-c`)  rather than the `-File` (`-f`) parameter.
See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: It is working when I used -Command instead -File but thing is ansible response is coming (but I see script executed successfully) any Idea what could be the issue?
"end_time": "2023-11-17T07:50:12+00:00", "exit_code": 1, "msg": "Failed to execute command", "name": "powershell.exe", "owner": "Administrator", "start_time": "2023-11-17T07:49:34+00:00"